# Why in this code count has been decremented?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, stack

Why in this code count has been  decremented first before deleting the last element of storage object?
In this way ,will it not delete the second last element instead of last?

```
var stack = function () {
  this.count = 0;
  this.storage = {};
  this.push = function (value) {
    this.storage[this.count] = value;
    this.count++;
  }
  this.pop = function () {
    if (this.count === 0) {
      return undefined;
    }
    else {
      this.count--;
      var result = this.storage[this.count];
      delete this.storage[this.count];
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count equals to index of the first free location in the data structure, then adding takes place at the current count which is incremented after, and by symmetry is decremented before to point to the last element in place which is freed, thus count points to the last freed location.

Answer (score 2):

In (most) programming languages, arrays are zero-based.

So, for `['foo']`, count will be `1`, but `'foo'` is at index `0`.

So, the last element in an array will ***always*** be at index `array.length - 1`.

---

That said, if you make `this.storage` an array, the whole `else` block can be replaced.

Since `this.storage` acts as an array any way, make it an array:

```
this.storage = [];
```

Then you can use:

```
else {
  this.count--;
  return this.storage.pop();
}
```

[`Array.prototype.pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) removes the last element from the array, and returns said element.

Answer (score 0):

because the array is 0 indexed, the first element is stored at the 0'th index, the 2nd at the 1'st index and so on

Comment: So, this is why count has been initialized to zero so that it can neutralize this effect.